# Why is etag "null" from the returned File object when uploading a file?

Tags: curl, etag, box-api

When I upload a file, I would like to have the etag so I can delete it afterwards. With the current API, the etag always returns null when uploading the file. Is there a way that I can get the etag without making 2 API calls: uploading the file -> get information about the file?

Even the documentation example returns null for the etag: http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file

Thanks.

Comment: Etag is a mechanism used for web cache validation, it prevents a proxy (or client) from downloading redundant data that hasn't changed. What use would it be when uploading? Since you are uploading, the data *obviously* just changed.

Comment: The notion of etag is not familiar for me. Box's API needs the etag when deleting a file from their API. I will find a workaround. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: What about uploading, and then doing a HEAD on the URL? This will give you all the headers, including whatever the server now thinks is the Etag.

Answer (score 2):

Etag calculation was separated from upload response as a performance optimization.   Until it is calculated (usually within a couple of 100 millis after the upload) we leave it as null.

As has already been mentioned, you can call a GET on the /files/ endpoint shortly after the upload completes, and the eTag value will be there.

We do have plans to move eTag calculation in parallel with the upload, and include it in the response to the POST /files/data call, but we'll only do it if the performance is what we consider to be reasonable.

Comment: (Jan 2013) Have you been able to start calculating the eTag in parallel with the upload?  I'm seeing (what appear to be) valid eTags returned following the POST and I want to verify that that they're trustworthy.

Comment: Yes, we moved the ETag calculation into a separate thread and got it processed in parallel with the rest of the upload.   By the time the upload is done, we now give you back the ETag in the upload response.